# Using JPA/Oracle can I have a unique constraint that ignores string case?

Tags: oracle, jpa

I have a db table with a column that is a String. I do not consider the case to be significant (e.g. "TEST == "test"). Unfortunately, it appears that JPA2 does, because both values are inserted into my table; I would like the second one to be rejected.

Is there a generic way to annotate an "ignore-case" unique constraint on a string column?

As an alternative, I could also consider putting a unique "ignore-case" constraint on the actual db column. Is that possible in Oracle 10?

What I don't want to do is write code, because this occurs often in this particular db.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with a function-based unique index

```
create unique index <index_name> on <table_name> (UPPER(<column_name>));
```

for Example

```
create table t111( col varchar2(10));
create unique index test_idx on t111 (UPPER(col));
insert into t111 values('test');
insert into t111 values ('TEST');
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for that. I will give it a go. I would actually prefer to tighten-up the db constraints that rely on using Java. Max